# Can't connect to WebServer inside (Vagrant) Virtualbox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Vagrant Box with Virtualbox as the provider. The guest OS is Windows Server 2012 R2. I use the private network setting from vagrant with an arbitrary ip, which is unique.
In the box, I have a Apache installed. I get a response from within the vm, if I open a browser. But when I try to connect from my host to the guest I get nothing at all.
I have checked if the "Listen" directiv is set to localhost only, but it isnt. It is set to *:8080
How can I get a response in the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward the port to the guest machine. See: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
end
```

Comment: I did this, and it didn't work as well. But, why would I need a port forwarding if I have a private network at all?

Comment: Because you have NAT for that private network. Any incoming packets are allowed only for existing connections. You need to punch holes in that NAT to allow incoming traffic for VM.

Comment: Check also the Windows firewall inside VM.

Comment: Is there any way to access the vm with the ip address without the port forwarding?

Comment: Yes, if you disable NAT. But then to give access to Internet for the VM, you need to add a static route on your router and you need to enable routing on your host machine.
Another solution would be to put the VM in the same network as your host and enable bridging between VM and the hosts NIC.